# how does a hypervisor knows that a privileged instruction happened inside a VM?

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

I've started reading about VMM and wondered to myself how does the hypervisor knows a privileged instruction (for ex, cpuid) happened inside a VM and not real OS ?

let's say I've executed *cpuid*, a trap will occur and a VMEXIT would happen, how does the hypevisor
would know that the instruction happened inside my regular OS or inside a VM ?

Answer (score 12):

First off, you are using the wrong terminology. When an OS runs on top of a hypervisor, ***the OS becomes the VM (virtual-machine) itself*** and ***the hypervisor is the VMM (=virtual machine monitor)***. A **VM** can also be called "***guest***". Thus: **OS on top of hypervisor = VM = guest** (these expressions mean the same thing).

Secondly, you tell the **CPU** that it's **executing inside the VM** from the moment you've executed **VMLAUNCH** or **VMRESUME**, assuming you're reading about Intel VMX. When for some reason the VM causes a hypervisor trap, we say that "***a VM-exit occured***" and the CPU knows it's no longer executing inside the VM. Thus:

- Between ***VMLAUNCH/VMRESUME*** executions and ***VM-exits*** we are in the **VM** and ***CPUID will trap*** (causing a **VM-exit**)
- Between ***VM-exits*** and ***VMLAUNCH/VMRESUME*** executions we are in the **VMM** (=hypervisor) and ***CPUID will NOT TRAP***, since we already are in the hypervisor

Answer (score 0):

Instructions that are privileged generate exceptions when executed in *user mode*.  The exception is usually an **undefined instruction** exception.  The *hypervisor* hooks this exception, inspects the executing instruction and then returns control to the *VM*.  When the *host* OS calls the same instruction, it is in a *supervisor* or elevated privilege and usually no *exception* is generated when it executes the instruction.  So generally, these issues are handled by the **CPU**.

However, if an instruction is not available on the processor (say *floating point emulation*), then the *hypervisor* may emulate for the *VM* and *chain* to the OS handler if not.  Possibly it may even allow the *OS* to handle the emulation for both *VMs* and *user tasks* in the *OS*.

So generally, this question is unanswerable for a generic CPU.  It depends on how the instruction is emulated in the *VM*.  However, the best case is that the *hypervisor* does not emulate any  *OS* instructions.  Emulations will not only slow down the *VMs*, but the entire **CPU**, including *user processes* in the host *OS*.

Comment: You didn't understand my question focus; maybe I should try to explina it again. I have one HVM VM running and a regular OS, how does the hypervisor knows that CPUID was executed *inside* the VM and not in the regular OS ? both will cause a trap to occur, how would it know that the trap belongs to the VM and not the OS ?

Comment: I did understand what you are saying.  I assume that `cpuid` is only allowed in x86 ring XX, which is supervised.  When the *guest OS* runs the instruction in **user mode**, the result is like an *undefined instruction*.  This traps to an exception/interrupt routine and the hyper-visor will emulate the instruction.  If the `CPUID` is allowed in user mode, then there is nothing the *hypervisor* can do.  From [Wikipedia's CPUID page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID), I assume it is the later as why would someone want to dis-allow a user to not *id* the CPU?